# Date requirement when checkbox is True in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

Hi my requirement is:  When select checkbox, then need to display Date as follow:

1. When checkbox selected, Date should be year ending  1231.

Pls find my code below in controller:

```
    component.set("v.SFYI",ShortFirst);   // SFYI is aura boolean attribute 
    var SFYI = component.get("v.SFYI");
    // alert(SFYI);   
    // Alert working corrrectly, when checkbox selected , Value display TRUE
    if(SFYI == "true") {    
        *******Here condition is not working, not sure is this correctline
        var today = $A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
        component.set('v.today', today);
        component.set("v.date",today);
    }
```

Issues getting:

`if(SFYI == true)`    --- getting issues this line, But alert showing correctly, But if condition not working
can you pls assist on this 
Thanks

Comment: what is type of attribute SFYI in your markup? If it is boolean, if(SFYI == "true") will never be satisfied. If it is a string, then it will return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `SFSY` is a checkbox, then you can't compare strings

Instead of this

`if(SFYI == "true") {`

You should do

`if (SFYI) {`

That is the simplest way of checking whether a variable is true or not

Comment: Thank you Sebastian......its working .

Comment: If it’s working, please mark the answer as accepted so others can benefit from it as well

Answer (score -1):

Or either you can drop the quotes "" . Just use if(SFYI == true) it will resolve the above issue.
Thanks!!

Comment: Hi..can we hide date field When checkbox is unchecked  AND when checked ..Date field should be visible ..Thanks

Comment: yes you can use else condition to hide it.